# Android App --> Displaying Local News

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app and am not sure if something like this exists or how to even approach it.  I would appreciate any advice.

In this app I would like to have a screen that displays only local news for a certain zip code.  I would of course type in the zip code but after I do this once it would take it from there.

What is the best way to do this?

I've read a bit about RSS feeds.  Is this the way to go?  Is there a particular RSS feel that will let me type in a zip code...and if so, how do I display this content inside a page of my app?

Maybe there is a website that specifically does this for android apps and I just need to set a url to this web page to consume the information?

Sorry if I'm not very informed about this.  This is my first app and I would really appreciate knowing how best to approach this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google News gives "information near you". It uses geolocation to know where you are and shows the news that happen in your area, maybe you can use that.

You can also use the RSS they provide for a certain area, for example, California:

http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&gl=us&as_occt=any&as_qdr=a&as_nloc=california&authuser=0&q=location:california&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

Comment: Do you have the URL to the Google News "information near you"?

Comment: It's here http://news.google.com/news/section?cf=all&ned=us&geo=detect_metro_area&ict=ln, but I think it does not have a proper RSS feed, but maybe you can do something with HTMLCleaner.

Comment: please share google news documentation link if it is documented.